# unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed with ChromeDriver Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using InstaPy which use Python and Selenium. I start the script per Cron and from time to time it crashes. So it'r really irregular, sometimes it runs well through. I'v posted on GitHub Repo as well already but didn't get an answer there, so i'm asking here now if someone has an idea why.

It's a digital ocean ubuntu server and i'm using it on headless mode. The driver version are visible on the log. here are error messages:

```
ERROR [2018-12-10 09:53:54] [user]  Error occurred while deleting cookies from web browser!
b'Message: invalid session id\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.15.0-42-generic x86_64)\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/InstaPy/instapy/util.py", line 1410, in smart_run
    yield
  File "./my_config.py", line 43, in <module>
    session.follow_user_followers(['xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx'], amount=100, randomize=True, interact=True)
  File "/root/InstaPy/instapy/instapy.py", line 2907, in follow_user_followers
    self.logfolder)
  File "/root/InstaPy/instapy/unfollow_util.py", line 883, in get_given_user_followers
    channel, jumps, logger, logfolder)
  File "/root/InstaPy/instapy/unfollow_util.py", line 722, in get_users_through_dialog
    person_list = dialog_username_extractor(buttons)
  File "/root/InstaPy/instapy/unfollow_util.py", line 747, in dialog_username_extractor
    person_list.append(person.find_element_by_xpath("../../../*")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 351, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 659, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.15.0-42-generic x86_64)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/InstaPy/instapy/instapy.py", line 3845, in end
    self.browser.delete_all_cookies()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 878, in delete_all_cookies
    self.execute(Command.DELETE_ALL_COOKIES)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: headless chrome=71.0.3578.80)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.15.0-42-generic x86_64)
```

Any idea what the reason could be and how to solve it?

Thanks for the inputs. And the guys from http://treestones.ch/ helped me out.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Though you see the error as:

```
Error occurred while deleting cookies from web browser!
b'Message: invalid session id\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.15.0-42-generic x86_64)\n'
```

The main exception is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
```

Your code trials would have given us some clues what going wrong.

---

### Solution

There are diverse solution to this issue. However as per [UnknownError: session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/20) this issue can be solved by either of the following solutions:

- Add the following `chrome_options`:

  ```
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  ```
- Chrome seem to crash in Docker containers on certain pages due to too small `/dev/shm`. So you may have to fix the small `/dev/shm` size.
- An example:

  ```
  sudo mount -t tmpfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=512M tmpfs /dev/shm
  ```
- It also works if you use `-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm` option to share *host* `/dev/shm`
- Another way to make it work would be to add the `chrome_options` as **`--disable-dev-shm-usage`**. This will force Chrome to use the `/tmp` directory instead. This may slow down the execution though since disk will be used instead of memory.

  ```
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  ```

---

### from tab crashed

**from tab crashed** was WIP(*Work In Progress*) with the *Chromium Team* for quite some time now which relates to *Linux attempting to always use /dev/shm for non-executable memory*. Here are the references :

- [Linux: Chrome/Chromium SIGBUS/Aw, Snap! on small /dev/shm](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522853)
- [Chrome crashes/fails to load when /dev/shm is too small, and location can't be overridden](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715363)
- As per [Comment61#Issue 736452](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=736452#c61) the fix seems to be have landed with **Chrome v65.0.3299.6**

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception from tab crashed error when executing from Jenkins CI server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518157/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-session-not-created-exception-fr/49518339#49518339)

Comment: similar issue for windows containers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959477/selenium-inside-windows-docker-container-fails-with-ff-chrome-session-deleted-b

Comment: I have the same error and did everything as suggested but did not solve my problem the error continues.
Any different suggestions?

Comment: This solution not work when selenium used with odoo 13

Comment: using the chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') argument ended my 5 hour search for fixing the tab crashes. Thank you soo much for sharing!

Comment: This is my second time revisiting this SO solution. At the end of the day looks like adding these options do mitigate the likelihood of `cannot determine loading status` and `from tab crash`, but from time to time I still face it, but it's rare enough like 1 out of 10-20 tests that I just deal it with re-attempting the test. I'm using latest chrome and selenium, so really hope the issue can be well investigated. Well perhaps it could be my ` /dev/shm` is too small for selenium sometimes, even if having `--disable-dev-shm-usage`.

Comment: @ShaungCheng `/dev/shm` holds the key to this problem.

Comment: This great answer doesn't solve my problem. I tried to create a new question but it got closed as duplicate. Any suggestion or changes over the last year which might help me?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66198126/selenium-chromedriver-failing-to-start-with-error-session-not-created-from-tab

Comment: This solution solved my issue. I'm inside a docker container and using `-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm` solve the issue

Comment: options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage") works!

Comment: you are a hero and a god. I logged in just to +1 you because of how elated I was when this worked.

Comment: --disable-dev-shm-usage did the jobs for me - thanks!

Answer (score 24):

In case someone is facing this problem with docker containers:

use the flag `--shm-size=2g` when creating the container and the error is gone.
This flag make the container to use the host's shared memory.

Example

```
$ docker run -d --net gridNet2020 --shm-size="2g" -e SE_OPTS="-browser applicationName=zChromeNodePdf30,browserName=chrome,maxInstances=1,version=78.0_debug_pdf" -e HUB_HOST=selenium-hub-3.141.59 -P -p 5700:5555 --name zChromeNodePdf30 -v /var/lib/docker/sharedFolder:/home/seluser/Downloads selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-xenon
```

Source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Comment: I think `--shm-size='64m' is the default, so try to keep it as a minimum

Comment: In a `docker-compose.yml`, this can be specified via `shm_size: 2g` for each service. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56655091/2066546

Comment: linking the relevant selenoid page to configure this: https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/blob/master/docs/browsers-configuration-file.adoc

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the following error on my Ubuntu server:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed   (Session
> info: headless chrome=86.0.4240.111)   (Driver info:
> chromedriver=2.41.578700
> (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux
> 5.4.0-1029-aws x86_64)

It turned out the the cause of the error was **insufficient disk space** on the server and the solution was to **extend my disk space**. You can check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328500/can-i-run-multiple-scraper-at-the-same-time-using-cron-jobs) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

We need to specify the shm memory separatly, --shm-size=2g
In case of docker,
use the following config - this working fine for me

---

services:
chrome:
image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210823
shm_size: 2gb

Answer (score 1):

The answers above solved my issue, but since i needed to run it from a docker-compose.yml i used this configuration which calls my regular unchanged DockerFile

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '1.0'
services:
  my_app:
    build:
      context: .
      #when building
      shm_size: 1gb
    #when running  
    shm_size: 1gb
```

DockerFile (selenium on Ubuntu -WSL-)

```
FROM python:3.10

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# install selenium
RUN pip install selenium==3.8.0


#install and prepar app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
# COPY . /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get install -y libnss3

ENV APP_DIR=/app/my_app
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

# COPY . ${APP_DIR} #not needed since we are mapping the volume in docker-compose

CMD [ "my_app.py" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
```

Comment: adding `shm_size: 1gb` to the `docker-compose.yml` file solved for me

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while trying to open a new web page with the **same driver** in `Chromium`. It worked fine in my local machine where I use `Chrome`.

**Did not worked:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {
        "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})

driver.get('url1')
# Do operations with url1

driver.get('url2')
# Do operations with url2 -> did not work and crashed
```

Below is the **solution**, I am using which is working for me. i.e re-initializing `the driver`

```
def setup_driver():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {
        "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})


setup_driver()
driver.get('url1')
# Do operations with url1
driver.close()

setup_driver()
driver.get('url2')
# Do operations with url2
driver.close()
```

Comment: In your "didn't work" example, did you close the driver at all? And did you get the error consistently? If you didn't close the driver at all and it wasn't consistent, then maybe what you encountered is what I described in my answer, so just closing is once at the end would probably suffice.

Comment: Yes, Indeed i closed at the end in the try which didn't worked as well. Also the crash was consistent. Not even passed once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the only possible cause and solution, but after thorough investigation of this error which I encountered every now and then, I found the following evidences:

1. In the log of the Selenium Grid nodes (which you can show by executing the following command on the docker host: `sudo docker logs <container-id>`) I found many errors reading: `[SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)`. From what I read, this error usually means that there are no available ports.
2. When showing the processes running inside a node (`sudo docker exec -it bash` and then `ps aux`), I found more than 300 instances of **chrome-driver** processes (you can count them using `ps aux|grep driver|wc -l`)

When running locally, I know that the **chrome-driver** process is normally invoked when you create an instance of `ChromeDriver` and is terminated when you call `driver.Quit()` (I work in C#, not Python). Therefore I concluded that some tests don't call `drive.Quit()`.

### The conclusion

In my case, I found that even though we had a call to `driver.Quit()` in the `[TearDown]` method (we use NUnit), we had some more code before that line, that could throw and exception. When one of these preceding lines threw an exception, the line that calls `driver.Quit()` is not reached, and therefore over time we were "leaking" **chrome-driver** processes on the Selenium Grid nodes. These orphan processes caused a resource leak of available ports (and probably also memory), which also caused the browser's page to crash.

### The solution

Given the above conclusion, the solution was pretty straight forward. We had to wrap the code that precedes `driver.Quit()` in a `try/finally`, and put the call to `driver.Quit()` in the `finally` clause, like this:

```
[TearDown]
public void MyTearDown()
{
       try
       {
              // Perform any tear down code you like, like saving screenshots, page source, etc.
       }
       finally
       {
              _driver?.Quit();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with the 30th January 2024 release version: **121.0.6167.139**

It's a chrome bug.

Downgraded to the previous version:
**120.0.6099.224** and started working again.

Reported it to Google. For more info [check here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13551#event-11724519319).
Google rejected it. The bug still appears in higher versions...

Answer (score -1):

```
Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed
(Session info: headless chrome=95.0.4638.69)
```

This error occurred because there was not enough waiting time for web pages to load

(The error message says the session got deleted because a webpage crashed. There's another problem where it can't figure out if the page is loading or not. After looking into it, I found out that the main issue was not waiting long enough for web pages to load. I figured this out by checking the errors, doing some tests, and reading about how sessions and crashes work in headless Chrome, version 95.0.4638.69.)

Comment: How on earth did you get to that conclusion for that error message???

Comment: @Christian he is very smart

Answer (score -3):

I was having the same problem, I checked the log at which point in my script the bug happened and I added some wait, ie, `time.sleep(2)` just before the bug, and my problem was fixed.