# How to fix Scrapy-Selenium not yielding output?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

Selenium requests works but not using scrapy-selenium. The page loads and I get a 200 response from the website, but I get no error as it isn't yielding any output.

```
class SeamdbTestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'steam_db_test'
    start_urls = ['https://steamdb.info/graph/']

    def start_requests(self):

        for link in self.start_urls:
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url=link, 
                wait_time= 10,        
                callback=self.parse)
        
    def parse(self, response):
        driver = response.meta['driver']
        initial_page = driver.page_source
        r = Selector(text=initial_page)
        table = r.xpath('//*[@id="table-apps"]/tbody')
        rows = table.css('tr[class= "app"]')[0:2]

        for element in rows:
            info_link = "https://steamdb.info" + element.css('::attr(href)').get()
            name = element.css('a ::text').get()
            yield {"Name": name, "Link": info_link}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a lot of code. How about something like this?

```py
from browserist import Browser

table_rows_xpath = "//*[@id='table-apps']/tbody/tr"

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://steamdb.info/graph/")
    number_of_rows = browser.tool.count_elements(table_rows_xpath)
    for i in range(1, number_of_rows + 1):
        game_xpath = f"{table_rows_xpath}[{i}]/td[3]/a"
        game_name = browser.get.text(game_xpath)
        game_relative_url = browser.get.url.from_link(game_xpath)
        game_absolute_url = f"https://steamdb.info{game_relative_url}"
        print(game_name, game_absolute_url)
```

Output:

```
Counter-Strike 2 https://steamdb.info/app/730/charts/
Dota 2 https://steamdb.info/app/570/charts/
Palworld https://steamdb.info/app/1623730/charts/
...
```

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, SeleniumRequest with scrapy is not always perfect. The same selement selection is worwking selenium with bs4 but getting empty output like you along with scrapy.

Scrapy-SeleniumRequest not working

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class SeamdbTestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'steam_db_test'
    start_urls = ['https://steamdb.info/graph/']

    def start_requests(self):

        for link in self.start_urls:
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url=link, 
                wait_time= 10,        
                callback=self.parse)
        
    def parse(self, response):
        driver = response.meta['driver']
        initial_page = driver.page_source
        r = Selector(text=initial_page)
        rows = r.css('table#table-apps tbody tr')
        
        for element in rows:
            info_link = "https://steamdb.info" + element.css('td:nth-child(3) > a::attr(href)').get()
            name = element.css('td:nth-child(3) > a::text').get()
            yield {"Name": name, "Link": info_link}
```

Selenium with bs4 is working fine:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#chrome to stay open
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

driver.get("https://steamdb.info/graph/")
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

for tr in soup.select('table#table-apps tbody tr'):
    link=tr.select_one('td:nth-child(3) > a').get('href')
    link="https://steamdb.info" +  link
    name = tr.select_one('td:nth-child(3) > a').text
    print(link)
    print(name)
```

**Output:**

```
https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/
Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
https://steamdb.info/app/570/graphs/
Dota 2
https://steamdb.info/app/578080/graphs/
PUBG: BATTLEGROUNDS
https://steamdb.info/app/1172470/graphs/
Apex Legends
https://steamdb.info/app/1599340/graphs/
Lost Ark
https://steamdb.info/app/271590/graphs/
Grand Theft Auto V
https://steamdb.info/app/440/graphs/
Team Fortress 2
https://steamdb.info/app/1446780/graphs/
MONSTER HUNTER RISE
https://steamdb.info/app/346110/graphs/
ARK: Survival Evolved
https://steamdb.info/app/252490/graphs/
Rust
https://steamdb.info/app/431960/graphs/
Wallpaper Engine
https://steamdb.info/app/1506830/graphs/
FIFA 22
https://steamdb.info/app/1085660/graphs/
Destiny 2
https://steamdb.info/app/1569040/graphs/
Football Manager 2022
https://steamdb.info/app/230410/graphs/
Warframe
https://steamdb.info/app/1203220/graphs/
NARAKA: BLADEPOINT
https://steamdb.info/app/359550/graphs/
Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege
https://steamdb.info/app/381210/graphs/
Dead by Daylight
https://steamdb.info/app/236390/graphs/
```

.. so on

Answer (score 0):

True
I was having the same issue when I was trying to scrape a website I used scrapy-selenium middleware to do the work, I was getting None for all of the objects that I tried to yield
however, things changed when I coded the same project in bs4 with selenium
I was able to get all the information I needed nice and easily still it crashed a few times, though i was able to sort it out through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902507/unknown-error-session-deleted-because-of-page-crash-from-unknown-error-cannot)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35639014)

Comment: Another workaround would be to use firefox webdriver in selenium instead of traditional chrome webdriver with bs4
this worked fine for me , and don' forget to use proper wait times in between the requests