# Seleniun Python not running in docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium parser that needs to be run in docker. When run on a local machine, the script works completely correctly. When running inside a container, it feels like selenium is not working, when searching any elements, I get an error that the element will not be found. Thus, I conclude that selenium does not run inside the docker, or it cannot integrate with the chrome browser.
I tried installing chrome browser, chrome driver inside container. Tried using a remote driver running inside another container. The result is always the same.
The highest priority is to run without using a remote driver. Looking forward to your advice, thanks everyone!

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

COPY . /usr/src/app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && apt-get install -y gnupg2 \
  && apt-get install -y curl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/src/app/chromedriver/


CMD python3 ./script.py
```

My Python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(r'chromedriver/chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

# webdriver mode
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
# user-agent
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                     "Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
# headless mode
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
# incognito mode
options.add_argument("--incognito")

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=service,
    options=options
)
```

Comment: Could you provide your `requirements.txt` as well?

Comment: Why don't you just use a docker image provided by selenium? It contains all the features neccessary to run your tests.
https://hub.docker.com/u/selenium

Comment: @MartinTovmassian
requirements.txt -->
selenium==4.3.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
lxml==4.9.1
requests==2.28.1
uvicorn==0.18.2
fastapi==0.79.0
celery==5.2.7
flower==1.1.0
fake_user_agent==0.0.15
chromedriver-binary==103.0.5060.134.0

Comment: @Tork 
When I use selenium/standalone-chrome I get the following - 
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5d29a9eaa0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: @Tork In the script I define the driver like this
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444", options=options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know your use case with Selenium and the actual error you get, but based on your Dockerfile and your Python script I tried to run the Selenium [Getting Started](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) example.

I have just added these two lines to your script:

```py
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
print("Python" in driver.title)
```

In the first run I faced this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/script.py", line 29, in <module>
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 447, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=103.0.5060.134)
Stacktrace:
```

So based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970825/5472004) I fixed the issue by declaring this argument: `options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")`

And then the script worked as expected.

Comment: This argument solved my problem. Now the script works in docker as it should. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`Docker run --shm-size=1gb image_name`

or

In chromeoptions in the `main.py` file or what is your file you can disable `shm-usage`

Google it.

Basically it fails due to small size of shm when running selenium with chrome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).