# Problem with Selenium webdriver on Python Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile

I've been working on a project to scrape a site using Selenium. The script was originally developed for Google Colab, but I'm attempting to move it to a Docker container running on an Ubuntu environment.

However, I'm facing some issues in the transition:

Google Colab specific lines, like mounting the drive, are not directly compatible with Docker. How can I replace or adapt this functionality for a regular environment?
When executing the Selenium script within the Docker container, the browser either crashes or doesn't start up at all. I suspect this might be due to memory issues or the browser configuration within the container.
Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# ... [rest of the imports and the main logic]

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Any advice or recommendations would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an error message of the crash? And what docker image do you use?

Comment: If it is about memory you can try adding `chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')`. You can try all the solutions listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970825/8784827

Comment: I used ubuntu:18.04 as image, I think it's a problem with chromedriver for selenium

`2023-10-27 00:26:46     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
2023-10-27 00:26:46 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'`